# Get all the data from one row in sqlitedatabase with the name_column and store it in listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, listview

I have coded a RecyclerView where I search for data from my SQLiteDatabase with the SearchAdapter. The MaterialSearchBar (PlaceHolder) only shows the names of the data from the Database. Now I want to select one item, which i choose in the searchbar and get all the other columns of that one row and store the data in a listview in another activity.

So my first question is, how can i get all data from one row, if i only have the name? Should I do it with a cursor? 
And my second question is, how should i store all the data from that one row in a listview in another activity?

Thank you for your help!

```
enter cclass SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView medid,name,menge,art,nummer;

    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        medid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.medid);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        menge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.menge);
        art = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.art);
        nummer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nummer);
    }
}

public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Drugs> drugs;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Drugs> drugs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.drugs = drugs;
    }

    public SearchAdapter() {

    }

    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.medikamentensuche,parent,false);
        return new SearchViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //String pharmaId,name,menge,art,preis,code,bezeichnung;
        holder.medid.setText(toString().valueOf(drugs.get(position).getMedID()));
        holder.name.setText(drugs.get(position).getName());
        holder.menge.setText(drugs.get(position).getMenge());
        holder.art.setText(drugs.get(position).getArt());
        holder.nummer.setText(drugs.get(position).getNummer());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return drugs.size();
    }
}
```

#### DataBaseOpenhelper class

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "medikamente.db";
    private static final String TABLE = "Medikamente";
    private static final int DB_VER = 1;

    public static final String ID = "MedID";
    public static final String NAME = "Handelsname";
    public static final String MENGE = "Mengenangabe";
    public static final String ART = "Mengenart";
    public static final String NUMMER = "Pharmanummer";

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

//neues Medikament hinzufügen
   public boolean insertNewEntry (String name, String mengenangabe, String mengenart, String pharmanummer) {

       SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put(NAME,name);
       values.put(MENGE,mengenangabe);
       values.put(ART,mengenart);
       values.put(NUMMER,pharmanummer);
       long result = db.insert("Medikamente",null,values);
       if (result == -1)
           return false;
        else
           return true;
    }

    public List<Drugs> getDrug() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        Log.d("in der DrugDatabases", "SQLiteQueryBuilder successful");


        //Kathi habe hier: "ATCCode", "BezeichnungATCCode" gelöscht
        String [] sqlSelect = {"MedID", "Handelsname", "Mengenangabe", "Mengenart", "Pharmanummer"};
        String tableName = "Medikamente";
        Log.d("in der DrugDatabases", " successful" + sqlSelect);

        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        List<Drugs> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do{
                Drugs drug = new Drugs();
                drug.setMedID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("MedID")));
                drug.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Handelsname")));
                drug.setMenge(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Mengenangabe")));
                drug.setArt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Mengenart")));
                drug.setNummer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pharmanummer")));

                result.add(drug);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }return result;
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"Handelsname" };
        String tableName = "Medikamente";

        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do{
                result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Handelsname" )));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }return result;
    }

    public List<Drugs> getDrugsByName(String name) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"MedID" ,"Handelsname" ,"Mengenangabe" ,"Mengenart" ,"Pharmanummer"};
        String tableName = "Medikamente";

        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "Handelsname LIKE ?",new String[]{"%"+name+"%"}, null, null, null);
        List<Drugs> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do{
                Drugs drug = new Drugs();
                drug.setMedID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("MedID")));
                drug.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Handelsname")));
                drug.setMenge(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Mengenangabe")));
                drug.setArt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Mengenart")));
                drug.setNummer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pharmanummer")));

                result.add(drug);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }return result;
    }
}
```

#### MedSucheActivity

```
public class MedSucheActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SearchAdapter adapter;
    TextView textView;



    MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
    List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseOpenHelper database;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_medsuchen);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hinzufügen);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MedTableActivity.class);
                TextView suche = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SuchMedikament);
                intent.putExtra("weitergabe",suche.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                //wichtig wenn man Daten zurück geben will von der 2.Activity
            }
        });
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SuchMedikament);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_search);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        //textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.versuch);

        //Datenbank
        database = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);

        //Searchbar
        materialSearchBar.setHint("Search");
        materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
        loadSuggestList();
        materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
                for(String search:suggestList) {
                   if (search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                       suggest.add(search);




                }
                materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                if(!enabled)
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
                startSearch(text.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

            }
        });

        //init Adapter default set all result
        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getDrug());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void startSearch(String text) {

       adapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getDrugsByName(text));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void loadSuggestList() {
        suggestList = database.getNames();
        materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
    }

    public void onHinzuClick(View v) {
        Log.d("msg","Auf Hinzufügen Button geklickt");
        Intent intent = new Intent (getBaseContext(),MedikamentHinzufugenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: Done. Hope you can understand better now!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. So my first question is, how can i get all data from one row, if i
>      only have the name?
> 2. And my second question is, how should i store all the data from that
>      one row in a listview in another activity?

**If** **`name`** is definitely going to be unique, which it appears that it may not be, then you can use that in conjunction with the `getDrugsByName` method to obtain  a list of Drug objects (1 if the name is unique). So **`name`** is all that would be required and this can be passed to another activity via an Intent Extra and thus retrieved from that Intent Extra, you can then use the `getDrugsbyName` method in that activity to then get all the data for the row (**for 2.**). Of course you could also pass all values via Intent Extras.

If **name** isn't necessarily unique then you could use **`MedId`** (column **`ID`**) (assuming that it's the PRIMARY KEY of the table and thus unique) instead of the **name**. You would probably have a method `getDrugById` in the DatabaseHelper class along the lines of (**for 2.**) :-

```
public Drugs getDrugById(long id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Drugs rv = new Drugs();
    rv.setMedID(-1); // set so that drug not found can be determined
    String whereclause = ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv.setMedID(id);
        rv.setName(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(NAME)));
        rv.setMenge(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MENGE)));
        rv.setArt(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(ART)));
        rv.setNummer(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(NUMMER)));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- **Notes**

  - The returned value should be checked for the MedID being -1, this indicating that there is no such row that matches the passed id.
  - Rather than risking mistyping names the CONSTANTS defined in the class have been used (you may wish to adopt this throughout).
  - Cursors should ALWAYS be closed when done with, otherwise an exception can occur.
  - The above assumes that the ID column is the PRIMARY KEY and that it is an alias of the **rowid** column. That is you have `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `ID INTEGER,..other columns.., PRIMARY KEY (ID)`
  - The above assumes the correct usage of the ID column i.e. that it is treated as a long not an int *(int is ok as long as the rows are limited, however SQLite allows rowid's as high as 9223372036854775807, which cannot be handled by an int)*.
  - This is the usual method, as using  an alias of **rowid** will likely be the most efficient.